# Swift 4: downloading image from firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, swift4

I have built a project that is supposed to download images from firebase for user profile pics. However, my app is crashing with this error:

> "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value"

Here is my code for downloading the image;

```
extension UIImageView {  
func downloadImage(from imgURL: String!) {
    let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imgURL)!)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
        (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
}
```

Here is where I download the image in my tableview cell;

```
cell.userImage.downloadImage(from: self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath!)
```

I am also getting an error when I select a user profile pick during sign-up;

> Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query
>   cancelled}

But I don't believe that is the problem because I have already added permissions in my info.plist. Thanks in advance to anyone willing to help!

Comment: Where is the error? I am guessing it's at `let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imgURL)!)`?

Comment: I'm not getting an error that doesn't let me build, its a fatal error in Thread 1 UIImageView.downloadImage(from:).

Comment: What is `imgURL` when you call the function. The error you receive means it's not a String you are passing into this func.

Comment: @Torewin `imgURL` should be the URL string for the profile image

Comment: Yes, I know. I am asking what is it equal to when you are passing it into your function. The error is saying that's it's either null or not a String as you are force unwrapping it. If that makes sense.

Comment: @Torewin So sorry, `imgURL` is supposed to be a place holder for the URL string. When I implement the function using `downloadImage(from: self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath!)` it should take the URL from `imagePath`, which is child of each user's information (from the firebase database). I'm basically declaring the type `imgURL` to be referenced as a string from imagePath. This is most likely not the way to go about things?

Comment: Can you confirm that it equals something when you run your app? A valid String? What does it equal before the error?

Comment: @Torewin I'm assuming it is nil, X-code is displaying that `imgURL` equals "image not found" which references my earlier code `let imagePath = value["urlToImage"] as? String ?? "Image not found"`.

Comment: Here is the debugger: `Optional<String>
  - some : "Image not found"`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Are you still experiencing this issue? Can you post the code on where you are calling your `downloadImage` for me?

Comment: Thanks for all your help! You were completely correct in pointing out that `imgURL` was null. Therefore I had to go back in my code and declare imgPath as a string. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. Glad you figured it out. Sorry for I wasn't clear at the beginning. Also, just a tip where you are declaring it - it should not be an optional value so you shouldn't need to do `String!`. It should always be a String before the function is called so perhaps a check would clean out any errors you may find.

Comment: Got it! and thanks again for all your help!